# Is there any way that we can build tableview without delegate?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I know we can build tableview using a datasource, conforming to that protocols. But can we build a tableview with out conforming to the protocols and not setting datasource?.

Solutions
1. Building n no views based on datasource array, and we need to keep that views in scrollview, handle dequeuing

Can any one suggest me the other options ?

These question was asked in an interview.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode you can construct a simple table with neither a delegate nor a data source, namely by configuring a static table in the storyboard.

Comment: _Your_ solution would not be a table view. If I were the interviewer, I wouldn't accept that answer.

Comment: sorry datasource i mean

Comment: I don't think OP meant the `UITableViewDelegate`, but was referring to setting the delegates for the 2 `UITableView` protocols after declaring conformance to them.